# How to convert every row of array to one line of string using php?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a huge array about `65000` rows and each row has `7` rows and this is some of the `print_r` output

```
[1904] => Array
    (
        [Open] => 1.27260
        [High] => 1.27550
        [Low] => 1.27190
        [Close] => 1.27380
        [Volume] => 571
        [MA50] => 1.269988
        [MA20] => 1.269315
    )
[1905] => Array
    (
        [Open] => 1.27390
        [High] => 1.27690
        [Low] => 1.27340
        [Close] => 1.27660
        [Volume] => 521
        [MA50] => 1.270326
        [MA20] => 1.269695
    )
```

I want an output it to text file like this not csv

```
1.27390 1.27690 1.27340 1.27660 521 1.270326 1.269695 //All the data of 1905 row
1.27260 1.27380 //here only Open and Close of 1904 (here I'm Confused)
```

Comment: Start writing code.

Comment: can you post PHP code which you have made?

Comment: You should iterate array and write every value in string.

Comment: How do you determine when you want all data and when you want only open and close???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate array and convert every row to string using [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). In loop add result to string variable.
You can use [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to do this work

```
$str = array_reduce($arr, function($carry, $item){
    return $carry.implode(" ", $item)."\n";
});
```

See result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/Z5WR2)

---

Or use `foreach()` to iterate array

```
$str = "";
foreach($arr as $row){
   $str .= implode(" ", $row)."\n";
}
echo $str;
```

See result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/Ncpp5)

Comment: The problem Im facing is not in converting array to string, but how to output data from the array like this order: 2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,7,6...

Comment: @SamihAbdelli The numbers ` 2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,7,6` is index of rows?

Comment: @SamihAbdelli But what is rule of this order?

Comment: @Mohammed, I'm working on FANN script, it need a training data , and in my case it must be in that order

Comment: sorry, i was mistaken in that order, it means nothing, problem solved, thank you mohammed